# How to iterate over each char in a string?

Tags: c++, string, char

I have a string where I need to grab each char and do some checking:

```
std::string key = "test"
int i = 0;
while (key.at(i))
{
    // do some checking
    i++;
}
```

The problem here is that, eventually, the index `i` will be out of range, so the system will crash. How can I fix this?

Comment: I suggest you read about the c++ string class. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: No, reading a null character won't crash. Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: the "key.at(i)" crashes when i is over the length of the string, says xcode.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I think OP is referring to going out of range. But this correction is certainly necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string key = "test"
for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
{
    //do some checking
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(auto i = key.cbegin(); i != key.cend(); ++i)
{
    // do some checking
    // call *i to get a char
}
```

Comment: If C++11 is involved, the code works as is (`s[s.length()]` is guaranteed to be zero for all `std::string`s).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Woah, that's interesting. I take it length() was changed to not include the null terminator? But... doesn't that break a lot of backwards compatibility...

Comment: It never included the null terminator (i.e. `std::string().length() == 0`).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Well, what changed with C++11 then?

Comment: @Dave, previously, reading `s[s.length()]` was undefined. Now it isn't. You're now allowed to read exactly one character beyond the end of the string (with `operator[]`; you're still not allowed to dereference `end()`).

Answer (score 1):

you can use a for loop like this.

```
#include <string>

std::string str("hello");

        for(auto &c : str) {
            std::cout << c << std::endl;
        }
```

Comment: Since `c` is a primitive char, `char c` rather than `auto &c` seems clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `std::for_each()` and provide a lambda function that will process each character, like this:

```
std::string key = "testing 123";
std::for_each(key.cbegin(), key.cend(), [](char c){ std::cout << c; });
```

This prints:

```
testing 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, considering a `string` variable. Just iterating over the characters:

```
cout << "Insert a phrase, please: ";
getline(cin, input);

for (char c: input) {
    cout << "Character: " << c << endl;
}
```

---

#### not the subject but, worth to mention...

In terms of user input, there's a difference between `cin >> variable` and `getline(cin, variable)`:

- `cin` stops the reading of characters, if encounters a blank space
- `getline(cin, variable)` reads from input, until it encounters EOL character

For more information on `getline()`:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline

---

### you might be interested on a complete example for further reference...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


string userInputCin() {
    string input;

    cout << "Insert a phrase, please: ";
    cin >> input;

    for (char c: input) {
        cout << "Character: " << c << endl;
    }

    return input;
}

string userInputCinGetline() {
    string input;

    cout << "Insert a phrase, please: ";
    getline(cin, input);

    for (char c: input) {
        cout << "Character: " << c << endl;
    }

    return input;
}

int main()
{
    int option;
    cout << "[Processing String Input]" << endl;
    cout << "\n1. with cin" << endl;
    cout << "2. with cin + getline" << "\n\n> ";
    cin >> option;
    switch (option) {
        case 1:
            userInputCin();
            break;
        case 2:
            cin.ignore(); // make sure to call this, if calling getline() after
            userInputCinGetline();
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to iterate through the characters of a **std::string** is as follows:

```
std::string key = "test"

for (char &ch : key) {
    printf("%c\n", ch);
}
```